# Exercise problem on existence of analytic function on a given domain which satisfies certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence of distinct points in the open unit disc $D(0, 1) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} z_n = 0$. Does there exist an analytic function $f$ on $D(0, 1)$ such that $f(z_n) = \sin (z_n)$ for all $n$.

**My approach:** Consider an analytic function $g(z) = f(z) - \sin z$, where $ f(z) $ is analytic function on $D(0, 1)$. This implies that $g(z_n) = 0$. Also, as per the given conditions sequence of zeros  $(z_n)$ of $g$ have limit point $0$ in $D(0, 1)$. Thus, by applying the identity theorem function $g$ must be identically zero and hence $f(z) = \sin z $. This confirms the existence of such function.

I would like to know whether my approach is right. Is there any other way o solve this problem. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Looks good to me. A rather odd question, however, since they are basically giving you the answer.

Comment: The *existence* is simply shown by choosing $f = \sin$. What you have shown is the *uniqueness.*

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you very much. Ya it was like true and false question.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for more giving your views.